# How to select HTML attributes from an Ajax HTML response preferably with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, request

I have an ajax request which returns a html based on the map Bounds, I need to target certain attributes within the response and store them in variables. The results I get from the response are bootstrap cards which have data-lng and data-lat attributes, how can I store the result properly so I can target the attribues and use them in a loop later? Thank you

**Response:**

```
<div id="property-1" class="col box-margin" pid="1">
  <div class="card property-card with-overlay v3" data-lng="15.1307613070715" data-lat="44.04613801824153" appId="2">
```

```
function initMap() {

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {

        var bounds = map.getBounds();
        var getNElng = bounds.getNorthEast().lng(); //max
        var getSWlng = bounds.getSouthWest().lng(); //min

        var getNElat = bounds.getNorthEast().lat(); //max
        var getSWlat = bounds.getSouthWest().lat(); //min

        $.ajax({

            url: '/property/ajax/html?range_lng=' + getSWlng + '|' + getNElng + '&range_lat=' + getSWlat + '|' + getNElat,

            success: function (r, status, jqXHR) {

                console.log(r);

                if (status == 'success') {

                    // var response = $('<html />').html(r);
                    var response = $(r);

                    var lat= response.find('data-lat');
                    var lng= response.find('data-lng');

                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(lat);

                } else {
                    console.log(status);
                }
            }

        });
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it is a question. Make your question in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** Based on original code

Your existing code is close:

```
var response = $(r);
var box = response.find('#property-1');
```

(added the `#` for ID)
however, given that your response is:

```
<div id="property-1" ...
```

the *root* element is already property-1 so it's not a child (and `.find()` looks at children)

You can either do

```
var response = $("<div></div>").html(r);
```

which gives you a *root* div that you can the use `.find` on, or you can do:

```
var response = $(r);
var box = response.filter('#property-1');
```

---

**EDIT** your edit changes things substantially

You now have

```
var response = $(r);
var lat = response.find('data-lat');
var lng = response.find('data-lng');
```

as you're not looking at the root element, the `$(r)` is fine, however the selectors for `data-lat`/`data-lng` are incorrect and should be:

```
var response = $(r);
var lat = response.find('[data-lat]').data("lat");
var lng = response.find('[data-lng]').data("lng");
```

---

**EXTRA**

When the response has multiple results, you can loop through them different ways, depending on what you're trying to get out.  Assuming they are all in the format of

```
<div data-lat...  data-lon...`
```

and all children (see first part) of one or more "root" elements, then you can loop them with:

```
$("[data-lat]").each((i, e) => {
    var lat = $(e).data("lat");
    var lng = $(e).data("lng");
});
```

or you can use `.map` to create an array of objects:

```
$("[data-lat]").map((i, e) => {
  return {
    lat : $(e).data("lat"),
    lng = $(e).data("lng")
  }    
}).toArray();
```

which will give you an array with an object with `.lat` and `.lng` properties.

---

You might like to consider changing your API (if you can) to only return what you need directly.  I suspect it's a 3rd-party API so you don't have that choice, but it's always the better choice if you have it.

Comment: One more question, sorry how do I loop through the resulst since I have more properties with many lat,lng data?    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

                    var lat = response[i].find('[data-lat]').data("lat");
                    var lng = response[i].find('[data-lng]').data("lng");
                    }

Comment: Thank you very very very much! :)

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept :)  (also helps people know you're not looking for an alternative answer)

Comment: unfortunately cannot up vote since I just created the account but will do once I get the privilege! thanks again!